# Facebook Share Action Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am unsure of what I have done wrong. This was working yesterday but when I came to use it today it was not working. Here is the code below:

```
        let facebookShareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
                // good to go, let's show the twitter composer
                let facebookComposer = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: ServiceTypeFacebook)
                facebookComposer.setInitialText(course.description)
                facebookComposer.addImage(course.image)
                facebookComposer.addURL(NSURL(string: course.programURL)!)

                self.presentViewController(facebookComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                // twitter isn't available. alert an error
                self.alert("Facebook Unavaiable", msg: "Go to - Settings > Facebook to set up your Facebook account")
            }
        }
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Did you change anything in the past day?

Comment: @EricD It's only comments just ignore it. Btw JohnGool has fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service type should be ...`= SLComposerViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceType`....

Try this below:

```
    let facebookShareAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
            // good to go, let's show the twitter composer
            let facebookComposer = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
            facebookComposer.setInitialText(course.description)
            facebookComposer.addImage(course.image)
            facebookComposer.addURL(NSURL(string: course.programURL)!)

            self.presentViewController(facebookComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // twitter isn't available. alert an error
            self.alert("Facebook Unavaiable", msg: "Go to - Settings > Facebook to set up your Facebook account")
        }
    }
```

That should fix it

Comment: No Problem!  Just try and solve the problem by your self next time, e.g. Google the problem or read through the code before asking on here.